# Can we add a trigger to a table on only a particular set of rows and not the whole table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I  have a table with various program ids,For eg: A,B,C and i don't want anyone to update or delete or insert for a particular program id,i.e B. Can i put a trigger only on a particular set of rows for this program id?

Comment: use an if else to compare program_id and give your statements inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only define a trigger for a table *as a whole*, not for a subset of the rows in a table. What you can do is have the trigger inspect the row and decide whether or not to take further action. In your case, you would need to check `new.program_id` (for insert) or `old.program_id` (for update or delete) and throw an exception or something if you find one of your restricted values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a before-update trigger to check the old and new program ID values, and raise an exception if either is one you want to protect.

Quick demo; first create the table and insert the 'protected' values before the trigger is there (or create the trigger and disable it temporarily):

```
create table t42 (program_id varchar2(1), data varchar2(20));

insert into t42 (program_id, data) values ('A', 'Some value');
insert into t42 (program_id, data) values ('B', 'Some value');
```

Then create the trigger that checks what is being changed:

```
create trigger t42_trig
before update or delete on t42
for each row
begin
  if :old.program_id in ('A', 'B', 'C')
      or :new.program_id in ('A', 'B', 'C') then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'You may not modify that program ID');  
  end if;
end;
/
```

Then try to insert a protected value:

```
insert into t42 (program_id, data) values ('C', 'Some value');

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20001: You may not modify that program ID
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG'
```

Inserting another value is still allowed:

```
insert into t42 (program_id, data) values ('D', 'Some value');

1 row inserted.

update t42 set data = 'New value' where program_id = 'D';

1 row updated.
```

Updating a protected value, or trying to change something else to a protected value, or deleting a protected value, are blocked; other changes are allowed:

```
update t42 set data = 'New value' where program_id = 'A';

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20001: You may not modify that program ID
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG'

update t42 set program_id = 'B' where program_id = 'D';

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20001: You may not modify that program ID
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG'

delete from t42 where program_id = 'A';

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-20001: You may not modify that program ID
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'STACKOVERFLOW.T42_TRIG'

delete from t42 where program_id = 'D';

1 row deleted.
```